# If I summarise someone elses work, how comprehensive do I need to be?

Tags: quotation

I am wondering into how much detail and comprehensiveness I need to go when summarising someone else's work in my own work. Given the need for brevity, I would think that one always needs to focus on the main points relevant to one's own work when summarising the work of others, but I am not sure.

Here is an example: let's say I wish to use a cultural history angle in my work and to support this approach i cite work X by another scholar. Said scholar shows the importance of the cultural history approach for the history of different regions, including region Y. In my case however, I only focus on region Y. Can I then simply say that work X has shown the usefulness of the cultural history approach for studying region Y, or do I also need to explain that he shows this for other regions as well so as to more comprehensively represent work X?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you propose is what I teach my students. So, yes, only pick the parts of an article or book that are relevant to your research question, and happily ignore everything else.

Comment: Thank you! I suppose this is true across disciplines?

Comment: I certainly don't want to read anything from a discipline where this rule does not apply...